chuppah besula/almana
We know that for a chuppah of a besula (virgin) all that is needed is the wedding canopy or yichud even not raoyi for biah (fit for cohabiting). Initially one should have yichud fit for cohabiting but if not it also works.
However, an Almanah (widow) needs a yichud fit for cohabiting. see mishna berura siman 339. and i saw in the piskei tshuvos (also siman 339)  that a beulah (non-virgin) may very possibly have a din like an almana and therefore requires a yichud fit for cohabiting.
My question is when performing the chuppah for a virgin maybe she really is non-virgin and the chuppah is not valid. What if she really is a non-virgin unknowingly the chuppah did not take effect?
question 2: the shulchan aruch, mishna brura (also siman 339) and many more write (correct me if im wrong. I think this is the universal halachah) that once one cohabits after the wedding even without chuppah fit for cohabiting ( even with a widow wich needs yichud fit for cohabiting) makes that the groom (chasan) is fully koneh his bride (kallah) as his wife.
Is this even with no eidim?

The way this is often handled today is that the term "bitulah" is essentially redefined as "a woman who has never been married," thus sidestepping the issue

Hi yohoshua k. Thank you for this info! do you have a place (mikor) where i can see this written? Thank you!
